# Extract end of month date from file path

Tags: r, string, date

I have a file path looking like this:

```
path<-"C:/My files/Summer/2021 Holiday/2021/April"
```

My goal is to write a code to extract end of the month date from it based on "2021" and "April" parts, in this format:
`30.04.2021`

I tried this:

`year_month<-tail(unlist(strsplit(path, "/")),2)`

And got this, and do not know how to continue.

```
[1] "2021"  "April"
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the package **lubridate** when dealing with dates. You can convert format and create dates very easly. Here's the cheatsheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/master/lubridate.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lubridate, we can form a date on the first of the month from the month and year of the date in the path.  Then, we can add one month and subtract one day to get the last day of the actual month.

```r
require(lubridate)

path <- "C:/My files/Summer/2021 Holiday/2021/April"
sub_path <- sub(".*/(?=.*/)", "", path, perl=TRUE)
parts <- strsplit(sub_path, "/")[[1]]
d <- ymd(as.Date(paste0("01", parts[2], parts[1]), "%d%B%Y")) %m+% months(1) - days(1)
d

[1] "2021-04-30"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of `basename` and `dirname` function to extract month and year. We can use `as.yearmon` to get the required output.

```
library(zoo)

path<-"C:/My files/Summer/2021 Holiday/2021/April"

paste(basename(path), basename(dirname(path))) |>
  as.yearmon() |>
  as.Date(frac = 1)

#[1] "2021-04-30"
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(lubridate::dmy('30.04.2021'),'month')-1
> [1] "2021-04-30"
lubridate::ceiling_date(lubridate::dmy('21.05.2021'),'month')-1
> [1] "2021-05-31"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I aim to achieve. My goal is to extract year and month directly from the path,  and avoid manual insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)

c("2021", "April") |>
  paste(collapse = " ") |>
  ym() |>
  ceiling_date("month") |>
  rollback() |>
  format("%d.%m.%Y")
```

Returns:

```
[1] "30.04.2021"
```

Comment: I agree, but the extraction problem is already solved in the question... I'm just adding on to it here.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be the following approach:

```
as.Date(paste0(tail(strsplit(path, '/')[[1]], 2), collapse = '-01-'), format = '%Y-%d-%b') -> x
x + as.integer(lubridate::days_in_month(x)) - 1 #first day of the month + number of days in a month - 1
```